# Single .scss file to autoprefixed/minified .css file with webpack instead of sass cli

Tags: webpack, sass, autoprefixer

I want to compile style.scss into style.min.css, applying autoprefixer and sourcemaps in the process.
With a script I would do something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "sass": "sass src/css/style.scss dist/style.css",
    "postsass": "postcss dist/style.css --use autoprefixer -r"
  },
```

but since I am already using webpack to build my module, I would like to use webpack to compile the scss too.
I don't need to extract included .css file from my .js files, I will not have them. For me, js and css and 2 separate things, so I don't need an "extractor" plugin.
I suppose I need instead a second entry point for webpack, one for main.js and one for style.scss.

I searched the web but I always find the usage of an extractor plugin, that reads "import style.scss" from some js files. I don't need that.

Thank you.